# This pipeline code runs fine as Direct runner but gives error when running on Dataflow runner 'name 'read_inputpath_date' is not defined'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

```py
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import os
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
import gzip
import json, io

from google.cloud import storage

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "credentials.json"


def read_inputpath_date(input_path):
    # Read the contents of the .jsonl.gz file from GCS
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name, file_name = input_path[5:].split("/", 1)
    # Get the GCS bucket and file object
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    # Download the .jsonl.gz file contents as bytes
    file_content = blob.download_as_bytes()
    # Read and parse the .jsonl.gz file
    data = []
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(file_content), mode='r') as f:
        for line in f:
            record = json.loads(line)
            data.append(record)
    logging.info('Done reading data from path{}'.format(input_path))
    return data


def process_messages(element):
    # Process the received Pub/Sub message
    message = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info('Received message: {}'.format(message))
    # Add your custom logic
    input_path = message["file_path"]
    input_path = 'gs://mf-staging-area/' + input_path
    table_name = message["table_name"]
    logging.info('Input path: {}'.format(input_path))
    logging.info('Table name: {}'.format(table_name))
    try:
        data = read_inputpath_date(input_path)
        for line in data:
            # Process each line of the file
            table_row = line['payload']
            logging.info('Line: {}'.format(line))
            logging.info('Table: {}'.format(table_name))
            logging.info('Row: {}'.format(table_row))
    except:
        logging.exception('Error occurred while reading input path: {}'.format(input_path))


def run():
    # Set the Google Cloud project and Pub/Sub subscription
    project_id = 'moneyfellows-data'
    subscription = 'projects/moneyfellows-data/subscriptions/streaming-topic-sub'

    # Create PipelineOptions with Dataflow runner
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    # Define the Dataflow pipeline
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        # Read messages from Pub/Sub subscription
        messages = (
                p
                | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
        )

        # Process the messages
        processed_messages = (
                messages
                | 'ProcessMessages' >> beam.ParDo(process_messages)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I tried to stream messages from pub/sub using Dataflow runner ,it worked fine on Direct runner but gives error 'name 'read_inputpath_date' is not defined' on Dataflow runner when reading the google cloud storage input path content and parse it as data variable.
I think it has something to do with context or scope of calling the function although it is defined before its call
Does anyone know what could be the reason behind that error and why is it only on Dataflow runner and not Directrunner ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you move the `read_inputpath_date` in a separate file and outside of main file, it should work :

Create `file_reader.py` file for example :

```py
def read_inputpath_date(input_path):
    # Read the contents of the .jsonl.gz file from GCS
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name, file_name = input_path[5:].split("/", 1)
    # Get the GCS bucket and file object
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    # Download the .jsonl.gz file contents as bytes
    file_content = blob.download_as_bytes()
    # Read and parse the .jsonl.gz file
    data = []
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(file_content), mode='r') as f:
        for line in f:
            record = json.loads(line)
            data.append(record)
    logging.info('Done reading data from path{}'.format(input_path))
    return data
```

Then import the `read_inputpath_date` method in the `main.py` file and `process_messages` method :

```py
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import os
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
import gzip
import json, io

from google.cloud import storage

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "credentials.json"

def process_messages(element):
    from your_root_folder.file_reader import read_inputpath_date

    # Process the received Pub/Sub message
    message = json.loads(element.decode('utf-8'))
    logging.info('Received message: {}'.format(message))
    # Add your custom logic
    input_path = message["file_path"]
    input_path = 'gs://mf-staging-area/' + input_path
    table_name = message["table_name"]
    logging.info('Input path: {}'.format(input_path))
    logging.info('Table name: {}'.format(table_name))
    try:
        data = read_inputpath_date(input_path)
        for line in data:
            # Process each line of the file
            table_row = line['payload']
            logging.info('Line: {}'.format(line))
            logging.info('Table: {}'.format(table_name))
            logging.info('Row: {}'.format(table_row))
    except:
        logging.exception('Error occurred while reading input path: {}'.format(input_path))


def run():
    # Set the Google Cloud project and Pub/Sub subscription
    project_id = 'moneyfellows-data'
    subscription = 'projects/moneyfellows-data/subscriptions/streaming-topic-sub'

    # Create PipelineOptions with Dataflow runner
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    # Define the Dataflow pipeline
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        # Read messages from Pub/Sub subscription
        messages = (
                p
                | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription)
        )

        # Process the messages
        processed_messages = (
                messages
                | 'ProcessMessages' >> beam.ParDo(process_messages)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Some treatment done inside in `DoFn` and workers are not visibles from the `main.py` file, one of possible solution is to move the method outside of main and import it inside the function where it will be used.

Comment: The same issue still persists